# Ext JS combo box value reset to wrong value after blur

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store

Ext JS Combo box has a store. I could see correct list of values pulled from service on typing and able to choose 2nd value from list. But after blur, combo box value is reset to 1st value from the list. Any idea ?

Comment: some code would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

Combo box set method was called by blur listener in parent component where the combo is referenced.